# Change the place holder text for the Ask a question Tags

Tags: feature-request, design

Currently the placeholder says:

> at least one tag such as (professionalism ethics management), max 5
>   tags

We should really remove ethics from this and replace it with resume, or interviewing as they seem to be far more popular.  In addition ethics is probably one of the most misused tags on the site.

Comment: but is it ethical to change the text there?

Comment: So, you're saying that we have unethical use of the ethics tag?  Do we need a pre-meeting meeting to determine if a meeting is required to set up a future meeting on the subject of that meeting?

Comment: Not unethical just improper.  its not unethical to make an honest mistake.

Answer (score 5):

I'll agree with that. The top five tags are [professionalism](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism), [interviewing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interviewing),[software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry),[resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume), and [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management). The only one I *wouldn't* use is [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry), as that one is often overused for situations that don't need it. (*How do I ask for a raise? Oh, I work in the software industry too.*)

Comment: That was my thought too.

Comment: I wonder what percentage of the users are NOT in the software industry on this site.

Comment: @RichardU Impossible to say but as you can see on the site analytics page, 75% of our traffic comes from off-site search engines. Regulars are probably overwhelmingly active in IT-related roles but we've got a lot of one-time askers and massive numbers of anonymous readers who get here because of SE's high search ranking and not through technical sites.